# PHP: Confirmation Dialog without using JavaScript?

Tags: php

I have a very simple form:

```
<form action="system/web/push.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card_input_push card_input_push_language">
            <select name="<?php echo PARAM_PUSH_LANGUAGE; ?>">
                <?php echo get_languages($mysqli); ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card_input card_input_push">
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo PARAM_PUSH_TITLE; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $language_array[LV_PUSH_INPUT_TITLE]; ?>"<?php echo set_value(PARAM_PUSH_TITLE); ?>required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card_input_push card_input_push_message">
            <textarea name="<?php echo PARAM_PUSH_MESSAGE; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $language_array[LV_PUSH_INPUT_MESSAGE]; ?>"<?php echo set_value(PARAM_PUSH_MESSAGE); ?>required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center card_input_push card_button_push_send">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="<?php echo REQUEST_SEND_GCM; ?>" value="<?php echo $language_array[LV_PUSH_INPUT_SEND]; ?>"><?php echo $language_array[LV_PUSH_INPUT_SEND]; ?></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i now press the submit button i dont want the post to perform instantly. I first want a confirmation dialog to show up with yes or no answers and only if the user says `yes` i want the post action to be performed.

What i **NOT** want is to use `JavaScript`. Is there a way to do that?

**EDIT**

Thank's for the answers. To satisfy all respondents i would like to tell you, why i dont want to use `JavaScript`. The answer is simple. I have no idea about `JavaScript`. I never have used it before but the project im working on (as always) has to be finished ASAP. That's the only reason.

Comment: You need JS for this. JS is what you use to make a static HTML-page interactive. All PHP-code is executed before the HTML-page even reaches the client and can't send things like confirmation dialogs. Why don't you want to use JS?

Comment: but why you don't use javascript for that? any reason?

Comment: *Question Is*: Why Don't You Want To Use **Javascript** ?

Comment: Don't want to use JS ... hmmm you could get retro and write it so it requires really old versions of Internet Explorer and use VBScript if you were, you know, really perverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way, use GET (not POST) the first time, on the PHP file check if GET was used and if so generate a form that sends confirmation form back to the user. Then make confirmation form to submit using POST and you are done.

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    // generate confirmation form
 }elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // process your data
 }
```

If anyone has access to a book called Head First PHP-MySQL they cover a similar example on page 280.

Comment: Technically that would work (kinda) but it sounds terrible; submitting the form to the server just to generate a dialogue box?

Comment: @CD001 that's exactly what OP wants. You can create confirmation form either with javascript or with PHP.

Comment: Actually... the OP says: "i dont want the post to perform instantly. I first want a confirmation dialog to show up". Btw, wouldn't be easier to always use POST but have a hidden field saying if it is confirmed or not? However, both ways are, in my opinion, bad design across the board.

Comment: Then he needs two forms; the first to gather the data and the second to say "are you sure"

Comment: I think the best thing would be for the OP to explain why he doesn't want to use JS. Then we might come up with a better alternative.

Comment: Yeah but if someone asked "What's the best way to rectally insert a tasty cake?", telling them to blend it into a paste and use a piping bag would technically be a correct response... but wouldn't it be better to ascertain *why* they don't just eat it?

Comment: @CD001 - Wouldn't be easier if he turned the cake into a liquid instead of a paste?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - greater potential for inner-thigh seepage though ... \*shudders\* probably best to end this train of thought :P

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this, with some css for design your dialog.

change your form with :

```
<form action="this_page">
```

If you submit, you call this page, display the dialog with a form, and when you submit with second form, you post to your needed php file.

```
if (isset($_POST['your_submit'] )) {
     echo "<yourdialog>";
     echo "<form action="system/web/push.php">";
     echo "content";
     echo "<submit yes>";
     echo "</form>";
     echo "</yourdialog>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow is:

- gather form data
- send to server
- get confirmation that that's what the user wants.
- if yes then process data.

If you want to do that all via php then the server's handling the full load, so you'll want two forms, one to collect and one to confirm. And you'll want to store the first form's data so you can process it according to the second form's result. A bit old fashioned but not difficult.

Comment: What if the question is "are you happy to send this data to our server?" - it's a bit late to ask that if they've already had to send the data to the server to generate the dialogue box...

Comment: that's the price you pay for using server side validation.